# Angular JEST Unit Test : TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

Below is the Angular Component Code where `armComponent` extendeds `BaseListComponent<armModel> implements OnInit` And I am trying to write a Unit Test for the component using JEST.

```
import { BaseListComponent } from 'path-to-base-list-component';
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { ConfirmationService, MessageService } from "primeng/api";
import { BreadcrumbService } from "src/app/common/services/breadcrumb.service";
import { MenuService } from "src/app/common/services/menu.service";
import { AcmsReportMapModel } from "../../../../models/acmsReportMap";
import { ARMService } from "path-to-arm-serivice";    
import { armListInput } from "path-to-armListInput";
import { SecurityUserService } from "path-to-SecurityUserService";
import { permissions } from "path-to-permissions";
import { CommonService } from "path-to-CommonService";
import { Components } from 'path-to-Components';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-arm-map',
    templateUrl: '../../base/list.component.html',
    providers: [{provide: armListInput  ,
        useFactory:(armService: ARMService, commonService: CommonService ) => new armListInput(armService, commonService) 
       , 
       deps:[ARMService, CommonService]
      }
    ]
  })
  export class armComponent 
  extends BaseListComponent<armModel>
  implements OnInit  {
  
   

    constructor(
       
        messageService: MessageService,
        confirmationService: ConfirmationService,
        breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService ,
        ar_Input: armListInput,
        router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private realUserService: SecurityUserService)
    {
        super(messageService,confirmationService,router,breadcrumbService,ar_Input);                         
        this.breadcrumbService.setItems(route,[{label: Components.arm.label}])
    }

    ngOnInit(): void{
            
     //Methods go here
         
          


    }
  }
```

But I was getting below error after running my UNIT Test :

> ```
>   TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
>
>     
>     export class AcmsReportMapComponent
> >   extends BaseListComponent<AcmsReportMapModel>
>              ^
>      implements OnInit
> ```

And below is is my JEST Unit Test code

```
import { BaseListComponent } from 'src/app/features/configuration/components/dataframe-acms/base/base-list-component';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { CommonService } from 'path-tocommon.service';
import { SecurityUserService } from 'path-tosecurity-user.service';
import { armModel } from 'path-to-armModel';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MessageService, ConfirmationService } from 'primeng/api';
import { of, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { BreadcrumbService } from 'path-tobreadcrumb.service';
import { armComponent } from 'apth-to-armComponent';
import { ARMService } from 'path-to-arm-serivice';
import { Components } from 'path-toconfiguration.components';
import { armListInput } from 'path-to-armListInput';
import { Action, BaseViewComponent } from 'src/app/common/components/base-view.component';
import { IComponentList } from '../../input-model/IComponentInput';

jest.mock('src/app/features/configuration/components/dataframe-acms/base/base-list-component');

describe("AcmsReportMapComponent", () => {

//   let component: BaseListComponent<AcmsReportMapComponent> ;
  let component: BaseListComponent<armModel> ;
  
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<armComponent>;
  
  let acmsReportMpService: ARMService;
  let commonService: CommonService;
  let realUserService: SecurityUserService;
  let breadcrumbService: BreadcrumbService;
  let route: ActivatedRoute;
  let messageService: MessageService;
  let confirmationService: ConfirmationService;
  let router: Router;
  let acmsReportInput: armListInput;

  const acmsReportMaps: armModel[] = [
    {
        acmsreportmap_id: 3,
        name: "acms",
        acmsreportmapversion_id:4,
        version: 5,
        airline:[],
        description: 'random',
        cnt: 4,
        isloading: true,
        filename:'test'

    }
    
]

class MockBaseListComponent<T> extends BaseViewComponent
  
  {
    // Added Requied Mocks and Properties in here
  }


  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [armComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: ARMService, useValue: {} },
        { provide: BaseListComponent, useClass: MockBaseListComponent },
        { provide: CommonService, useValue: {getAcmsReportMapData:jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(acmsReportMaps))} },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {} },
        { provide: SecurityUserService, useValue: {userHasPermission: jest.fn()} },
        { provide: MessageService, useValue: {add: jest.fn()} },
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useValue: {} },
        { provide: Router, useValue: { navigate: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true)) } },
        { provide: BreadcrumbService, useValue: { setItems: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of(ActivatedRoute, [{ label: 'Recorders' }])) } },
        { provide: ConfirmationService, useValue: { confirm: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of()) } }

    ],
    }).compileComponents();
    // fixture2 = TestBed.createComponent(BaseListComponent<AcmsReportMapComponent>);
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(armComponent);
    realUserService = TestBed.inject(SecurityUserService);
    commonService = TestBed.inject(CommonService);
    breadcrumbService = TestBed.inject(BreadcrumbService);
    route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);
    messageService = TestBed.inject(MessageService);
    confirmationService = TestBed.inject(ConfirmationService);
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    component = fixture.componentInstance
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(armComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    acmsReportMpService = TestBed.inject(ARMService);
    commonService = TestBed.inject(CommonService);
  });

  

  describe('Initialization', () => {
    it('should call getAllData to load list of Acms Report Maps on visit', () => {
            // ARRANGE
            jest.spyOn(realUserService, 'userHasPermission')
            .mockReturnValueOnce(true) // for permissions.config.recorder.create
            .mockReturnValueOnce(true) // for permissions.config.recorder.edit
            .mockReturnValueOnce(true); // for permissions.config.recorder.delete
      
            const getAllData = jest.spyOn(component, 'getAllData')
      
            // ACT
            component;
      
            //ASSERT
            expect(getAllData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
            expect(breadcrumbService.setItems).toHaveBeenCalledWith(route, [{ label: Components.arm.label }]);
            
    });
  });
})
```

Can I know what wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Where are you importing `BaseListComponent`? It's not in the import list of your actual component.

Comment: @DanielB I have them imported at the top, forgot to put whilst modifying the code to paste here